# Recurrence Question involving logarithm

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can anyone please solve this recurrence

$$T(n)=T(3\sqrt n)+\log n.$$

It came in my paper. I want to know whether the following answer is right or wrong:

My answer: $T(n)=\log^3 n.$

Comment: I am tempted to say: yes, the result is $\log(n)^3$, that's all. Besides, what do you mean when you say "it came in my paper" ?

Answer (score -1):

For $n=9$ the recurrence $T(n)=T(3\sqrt n)+\lg n$ gives

$T(9)=T(9)+\lg 9$,

hence $\lg9=0$  ??

Something wents wrong ...

Comment: What the OP has in mind is an **asymptotic behavior**. The word "recurrence" is maybe misleading: this is the way it is also named in  complexity analysis of algorithms

Comment: Sorry for the typing confusion

Comment: T(3√n) means cube root of n